# Lagrange multiplier derivative condition

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

For the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda g(\mathbf{x})$, I read that $\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial\lambda$ must equal $0$. Could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\frac{\partial \mathcal L (x,\lambda)}{\partial \lambda} =0 $ just says that $g(x) = 0$.  This must be satisfied, of course, if $x$ is a minimizer of $f$ subject to the constraint that $g$ is $0$.

Comment: Gotcha. So that's why, in order to find the solution with a given constraint, you take the derivative with respect to all the variables AND with respect to $\lambda$ (because the latter is just another way to express that constraint must equal 0). Thanks!